# Finding the result of $xyz$

Tags: exponential-function

$$2^x = 3$$
$$5^y = 2$$
$$3^z = 125$$

Find the result of  $xyz$

To get $xyz$, I've tried to multiply all together.

$$2^x . 5^y . 3^z = 750$$

Unfortunalety, I've gone too wrong as in my perspective. Can you assist? I'd like to get your professional tips.

**EDIT:** I'm trying to solve this question by using exponential properties.

Comment: You can also write $750$ as $5^332$

Comment: @LeylaAlkan harika

Comment: This should have been typed by $5^3\cdot 3\cdot 2$@user21820

Comment: @LeylaAlkan: Oh okay that's fine. I seriously thought you meant to have nothing in-between. So my first comment is no longer needed. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$5^{xyz}=(5^y)^{xz}=2^{xz}=(2^x)^z=3^z=125$$

Answer (score 2):

Solve for each $x=\log_2(3)$, $y=\log_5(2)$ and $z=\log_3(125)$.

The product would be $xyz=\log_2(3)\log_5(2)\log_3(125)$.

Very likely they will examine also the possibility of some simplification.

---

For the new requirement:

Raise the first equation to $z$. You get $2^{xz}=3^z=125=5^3=2^{3/y}$.

Raise again, but to $y$ and get $2^{xyz}=2^3$.

Comment: I don't want to use logarithm.

Comment: @Flisch Sure, see the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

taking the logarithm we get $$x=\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$$
$$y=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(5)}$$
$$z=\frac{\ln(125)}{\ln(3)}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Typo in the y expression.